# Unable to call the javascript function from HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, onload

I've a HTMLfile  as below sof.html and a Javascript file sofjs.js, which I'm importing inside the HTML & calling it's functions in `onload()` in `<body onload>`  from HTML. Code snippet below.

However, I'm noticing that only the HTML content is getting displayed and not the data that I've included in the Javascript's function. 
Using Javascript's `innerHTML` I want to display the content.

I'm very new to HTML and Javascript and experimenting this for first time. So please be easy on me.

**HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset = "UTF - 8">
 <style> thead { color: black;} tbody {  color: blue; } table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; } </style>
 <title>SOmeTitle</title>
 <script type="text / javascript">
 function activateTab(pageId) {var tabCtrl = document.getElementById('tabCtrl');var pageToActivate = document.getElementById(pageId);for (var i = 0; i < tabCtrl.childNodes.length; i++) {var node = tabCtrl.childNodes[i];if (node.nodeType == 1) {node.style.display = (node == pageToActivate) ? 'block' : 'none';}}}
 </script> 

 <script src ="batch1.js"type="text/javascript"> </script>
 <script src ="batch2.js"type="text/javascript"> </script> 
 <script src ="batch3.js"type="text/javascript"> </script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> function loadAll(){ batch1()}<!--;batch2();batch3(); -->}</script>
 </head>
 <body onload="loadAll()">
 "<h1 align="center"> SOmeTitle120.0</h1>
 <h3 align="right">Log Capture Time =Sat Aug 19 22:34:53 2017</h3>
<h3 align="left">IP Address = 127.0.0.1</h3>

<div id = "header">
<ul>
<li><a href = "javascript:activateTab('batch1')"id ="tb1">batch1</a></li>
<li><a href = "javascript:activateTab('batch2')"id ="tb1">batch2</a></li>
<li><a href = "javascript:activateTab('batch3')"id ="tb1">batch3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
<div id="tabCtrl">
<div id = "batch1" style = "display: block<div id="batch1"style="display: block; " name="batch1"><br>Select these</br> </div>
<div id = "batch2" style = "display: none<div id="batch1"style="display: block; " name="batch2"><br>Select these</br> </div>
<div id = "batch3" style = "display: none<div id="batch1"style="display: block; " name="batch3"><br>Select these</br></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript file:**

```
function batch1 () {
    document.getElementById('batch1').innerHTML = " 
    <ul><li><a href = "#Applications">Applications</a></li></ul> 
    <ul><li><a href = "#2ndTableApplications">2ndTableApplications</a></li></ul>
    <a name = "Applications"></a>
    <br />
    <h1> 
    <center>Applications</h1> <center> <br /> <br /> <br />
    <table border="1" style="width:300px">
    <tr> <th><b><center>Apps_1</center></b></th></tr>
    <thead> 
    <tr><th>Sl NO</th><th>Appname</th><th>appver</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr><th>1</th><th>Visual studio</th><th>13.5</th></tr>
    <tr><th>2</th><th>Android studio</th><th>11.5</th></tr>
    <tr><th>3</th><th>notepad</th><th>17</th></tr>
    <tr><th>4</th><th>notepad++</th><th>87</th></tr>
    <tr><th>1</th><th>Visual studio</th><th>13.5</th></tr>
    <tr> <th><b><center>Apps_2<center><b></th></tr>
    <tr><th>5</th><th>Visual studio</th><th>13.5</th></tr>
    <tr><th>6</th><th>Android studio</th><th>11.5</th></tr>
    <tr><th>7</th><th>xmlwriter</th><th>17</th></tr>
    <tr><th>8</th><th>notepad++</th><th>87</th></tr>
    </table>
    <a name = "2ndTableApplications>"</a>
    <br /> 
    <h1> <center>2ndTableApplications</h1>
    <center> 
    <br /> <br /> <br />
    <table border="1" style="width:300px">
    <tr> <th><b><center>MSapps<center><b></th></tr>
    <thead> 
    <tr><th>MS Sl NO</th><th>MSAppname</th><th>MSappver</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr><th>m1</th><th>MSapp1</th><th>13.5</th></tr>
    <tr><th>m2</th><th>msapp2</th><th>11.5</th></tr>
    <tr><th>m3</th><th>msapp3</th><th>17</th></tr>
    <tr><th>m4</th><th>msapp4</th><th>87</th></tr> ";
}
```

Comment: Try moving `<script type="text/javascript"> function loadAll(){ batch1()}<!--;batch2();batch3(); -->}</script>` to the end of `body`..ie just before the closing of `</body>~

Comment: Some things I saw immediately: `(1)` You don't have an element with the ID "Software" for your JS to work with. `(2)` You're not calling your `Software()` JS function anywhere, so it will never run. `(3)` You can't have line breaks (as you do) in a JS string (your innerHTML) without concatenating multiple lines.  `(4)` You have quotation marks in your JS string, which even if it didn't have the line breaks, would effectively end the string. Change them to single quotes.

Comment: @Lal: But I'm using loadAll() in <body onload()>. SO if i put loadAll() definition in end of <body> how will it work ?

Comment: It will work...you jut give a try..

Comment: @Lal: it didn't work. I tried. No change in output.

Comment: Any errors in your browser console??

Comment: Did you check browser console(F12 or Ctrl + Shift + i) and then click on console tab, it will give you the error @codeLover, I feel that the error is `<!-- batch2();batch3() -->` because in Javascript you will have to use `//` or `/*  */` for commenting, HTML comment i.e. `<!-- -->` will not work in Javascript

Comment: @JonUleis; Regarding the Software tags i corrected it. I replaced the "" with ' but n change.   Also i didn't get the line break point you mentioned. Did you mean <br /> tags.

Comment: No errors in console seen.

Comment: You're setting innerHTML to a string that spans multiple lines of JavaScript - that's not allowed in traditional JS without string concatenation, like `string = "Line 1" + (newline here) "Line 2"`

Comment: SO if i remove the "newline" (\n) from the javascript string (innerHTML), will it work ? @JonUleis

Comment: If there are no other problems, yes.

Comment: Strange part is that even if I include a function which is holding very basic HTML like innerHTML="<p>hello</p>" in ait  fJS file doesn't get called.But this basic HTML thingy works when JS function is inside html <script>.  However, my huge HTML string in JS function doesn't work in both cases.

Comment: @JonUleis: i tried removing all newlines but still doesn't work.

Comment: @: Thanks for the answer. The solution you suggested of removing newline chracters (\n) & using single quotes worked fine :) However, it's working if I'm defining this function in the HTML file's <Script> tag  but the very sma efunction defined in JS file doesn't work.   Actually no file defined in JS is working for me. Did i miss something basic.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jon Uleis said you can't have line break inside js string

```js
    document.getElementById('batch1').innerHTML ='<ul><li><a href = "#Applications">Applications</a></li></ul><ul><li><a href = "#2ndTableApplications">2ndTableApplications</a></li></ul><a name = "Applications"></a><br /><h1> <center>Applications</h1> <center> <br /> <br /> <br /><table border="1" style="width:300px"><tr> <th><b><center>Apps_1</center></b></th></tr> <thead>  <tr><th>Sl NO</th><th>Appname</th><th>appver</th></tr>   </thead>   <tbody> <tr><th>1</th><th>Visual studio</th><th>13.5</th></tr> <tr><th>2</th><th>Android studio</th><th>11.5</th></tr> <tr><th>3</th><th>notepad</th><th>17</th></tr>   <tr><th>4</th><th>notepad++</th><th>87</th></tr>   <tr><th>1</th><th>Visual studio</th><th>13.5</th></tr>   <tr> <th><b><center>Apps_2<center><b></th></tr>  <tr><th>5</th><th>Visual studio</th><th>13.5</th></tr> <tr><th>6</th><th>Android studio</th><th>11.5</th></tr> <tr><th>7</th><th>xmlwriter</th><th>17</th></tr>  <tr><th>8</th><th>notepad++</th><th>87</th></tr>   </table>  <a name = "2ndTableApplications>"</a>    <br />    <h1> <center>2ndTableApplications</h1>  <center>     <br /> <br /> <br />   <table border="1" style="width:300px"> <tr> <th><b><center>MSapps<center><b></th></tr>   <thead>    <tr><th>MS Sl NO</th><th>MSAppname</th><th>MSappver</th></tr>   </thead>   <tbody>  <tr><th>m1</th><th>MSapp1</th><th>13.5</th></tr>   <tr><th>m2</th><th>msapp2</th><th>11.5</th></tr>  <tr><th>m3</th><th>msapp3</th><th>17</th></tr>  <tr><th>m4</th><th>msapp4</th><th>87</th></tr> ';
```

```html
<h1 align="center"> SOmeTitle120.0</h1>
 <h3 align="right">Log Capture Time =Sat Aug 19 22:34:53 2017</h3>
<h3 align="left">IP Address = 127.0.0.1</h3>

<div id = "header">
<ul>
<li><a href = "javascript:activateTab('batch1')"id ="tb1">batch1</a></li>
<li><a href = "javascript:activateTab('batch2')"id ="tb1">batch2</a></li>
<li><a href = "javascript:activateTab('batch3')"id ="tb1">batch3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
<div id="tabCtrl">
<div id = "batch1" style = "display: block">

</div><div id="batch1"style="display: block; " name="batch1">Select these </div><br>
<div id = "batch2" style = "display: none">

</div><div id="batch1" style="display: block; " name="batch2">Select these </div><br>
<div id = "batch3" style = "display: none">

</div><div id="batch1"style="display: block; " name="batch3">Select these</div><br>
</div>
</div>
<div id="batch1">
</div>
```